# Export data of text table as .csv (Tableau)

Tags: tableau-api

I'd like to export the data of the text table in the view as it is (refer attached image). Generally for charts, I right click the chart and select 'view data' and then 'export all' to export the entire data as a csv file. However, in a text table, I'm not able select the entire data to view and export (only a particular row gets selected). I cannot export as crosstab to excel using the worksheet tab on top as the data is above the excel rows limit.

[image: View that I need to export]

Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish the export of this view to csv?

(I'm using Tableau Desktop 2020.2.2)

Comment: >Worksheet>Export>Data may export your data to MS Access format, from there you can easily export it to csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of these options from tableau menu-

- Worksheet > Export > Data (this will export data to mdb file)
- data > sheet_name > export to csv > sheet_name

[image]

- **ctrl + C / (alt then w then c then c )and paste data on a textpad/notepad**

[image]

If you are using filters, I think all of the data will be extracted, please check these options.

Comment: In the second method mentioned, after selecting the Data tab, there's no option to select a particular sheet from which data should be exported. Can you let me know if I'm missing something here?

Comment: Not data tab but data menu

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Data menu.

Comment: see screenshots added

Comment: Got it! Thanks for elaborating.